# Unable to connect SonarQube with SQL server

Tags: sonarqube, mssql-jdbc

I am using sonarQube and want to connect to sql server db. I ran following command:

```
 sonar-scanner -D sonar.projectKey=MyProject -D sonar.sources=. -D sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver:localhost;databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=true
```

but I am getting below error:-

```
databaseName=sonar : The term 'databaseName=sonar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:241
+ ... -D sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver:localhost;databaseName=sonar;integra ...
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (databaseName=sonar:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put spaces after the 'define' (`-D`) parameters:

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=MyProject -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver:localhost;databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=true
```